# Phonon backend plugin could not be loaded

Tags: 14.04

I built Minitube 2.5.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit smoothly but does not play any video.I have installed `phonon, phonon-backend-vlc, phonon4qt5-backend-null, libphonon4, libphonon4qt5-4, python-qt4, libphonon4qt5-dev` .

When i tried to run `minitube` command, it shows foloowing error :

```
$ minitube
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to Phonon::AudioOutput ( no objectName )
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to Phonon::VideoWidget ( no objectName )
```

What else do I need? How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced a similar issue, as described in [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839903/gwenview-phonon-backend-plugin-could-not-be-loaded).

After some tries, I have realised that there are separate packages for phonon qt5.

The installation of the following packages solved the issue on my system:

```
sudo apt install phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer phonon4qt5-backend-vlc
```

Now, the installation of these packages should probably be recommended from the gwenview package, so this is probably a packaging bug.

Comment: Doesn't work with Okular 1.10. Still the same error