# gwenview - phonon backend plugin could not be loaded

Tags: 16.10, qt5, phonon

I have Gwenview installed in Ubuntu 16.10, and I was not able to play videos. The console output gives this error:

```
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
```

I had tried several options around, including the installation of `phonon-backends-vlc`, which did not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

After some tries, I have realised that there are separate packages for phonon qt5.

The installation of the following packages solved the issue on my system:

```
sudo apt install phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer phonon4qt5-backend-vlc
```

Now, the installation of these packages should probably be recommended from the gwenview package, so this is probably a packaging bug.

Comment: Had a trouble with konversation's notification won't play. And this fixes it.